# Same font-style than comment in Visual Code

Tags: fonts, visual-studio-code, italic

im using Operator Mono

Currently my comments are in italics. How can I make all my code in italic too?
Thanks :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a "Operator-Font" specific answer.
If you have at least the "Operator Mono" package installed, you can try to switch the value for `editor.fontFamily` from `Operator Mono Light` to `Operator Mono Light Italic`.
Font styles have to be given with their explicit font name.